Evaluating $ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (\infty, \infty)}(1 - a^x)^y $
I need to know the limit of the following formula for a reliability estimation that I'm doing:
$$  \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (\infty, \infty)}(1 - a^x)^y $$
$a$ is a constant value between zero and one (eclusive bounds). If it makes a difference, we can assume a to be 0.5 for simplicity.
Unfortunately, I'm a little out of my depth here (as is wolfram alpha).
I have no idea if this is even defined. Could anybody give me some help?

You have to specify what you exactly mean by that limit.

If there is no relationship between $x$ and $y$, the limit doesn't exist.
From the well-known $$\lim_{t\to0}(1-t)^{1/t}=e^{-1},$$ if you put $y=c/a^x$ for $c>0$ the limit is $e^{-c}$, so any number in $[0,1]$ can be achieved. This tells you that if $x,y$ are free, the values of the expression will roam freely through $[0,1]$. Said in another way, if you fix $\varepsilon>0$, $s\in [0,1] $ and $k>0$, there exist $x,y>k$ and such that $$|s-(1-a^x)^y|<\varepsilon.$$

Thank you so much for the quick answer! I tried to derive this known formula shape from my original one using the suggested y=c/a^x, but I am not quite getting there. Could you be so kind to provide one or two intermediate steps?

I can try to help if you ask a more concrete question. The function $f(t)=(1-t)^{1/t}$ is continuous at $0$ if you define $f(0)=e^{-1}$. As $a^x\to0$ as $x\to\infty$, $f(a^x)\to e^{-1}$ when $x\to\infty$. Then $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-a^x)^{c/a^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(a^x)^c=e^{-c}.$$

Ah, now it's simple enough for me! Sincere thanks you for help, and sorry for my limited math skills, I'm just a mere programmer :).

Glad I could help!
